# How to make Custom Dialog look like Alert Dialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, customdialog

I've created my own (custom) Dialog. But would like to have its style like original [Alert Dialog](http://developer.android.com/images/dialog_buttons.png). I.e. with dark title background and grey buttons background on the bottom.
Is there any ready-for-use xml with the same? (so, I wouldn't worry about exact colors, heights, font sizes etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This answer is incorrect**

Use `Theme.Dialog.Alert`

From [themes.xml](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/themes.xml):

```
<!-- Default theme for alert dialog windows, which is used by the
        {@link android.app.AlertDialog} class.  This is basically a dialog
         but sets the background to empty so it can do two-tone backgrounds. -->
<style name="Theme.Dialog.Alert" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="windowTitleStyle">@android:style/DialogWindowTitle</item>
    <item name="windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

This can then be applied within an XML layout or Android manifest, as [referenced here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html):

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog.Alert">
```

Or onto an Activity using [`setTheme(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#setTheme%28int%29). However, this does not seem to be a recommended practice. Simple sample code shown in this [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4394).

Comment: Thanks, @Karl. How can I apply that to my own dialog?

Comment: That depends on how you have defined your dialog - either by within XML or programmatically. Programmatic application of themes seems to not be recommended. I've updated my answer slightly. Also see this link: http://www.anddev.org/applying_a_theme_to_your_application-t817.html

Comment: My answer is incorrect. Testing, I see that Theme.Dialog.Alert is not even public. It's only used by the AlertDialog class as a simple template. The real styling is later hard-coded within the class. Sorry.

Comment: What else I can try then? How to read these standard colors/field heights to apply them to my dialog?

Comment: You will have to style the dialog yourself. Within [themes.xml](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/themes.xml) is the section for `<style name="Theme.Dialog">`, this lists all of the necessary styling required to make a plain dialog. See [Applying Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) if you are uncertain how to use them. You may also be able to rewrite your dialog class to include use or extend [AlertDialog.Buider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html)

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem, wanted to create an Activity having the same UI as AlertDialog. I found it's a little difficult. Finally, I created a transparent activity and started an AlertDialog in it to resolve.